# Getting Results from AppInvite Google android

Tags: android, google-app-invites

I am using Google Appinvite Api in my android appication to send invitation to friends.

I am able to send the request and its working fine. But i want to track the friends to whom i have send request through my app.

This is the code where i get the Invitation Id.

But how can i get the send person name or email from the Invitation Id.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_INVITE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String[] ids = AppInviteInvitation.getInvitationIds(resultCode, data);
            Log.d("TAG", getString(R.string.sent_invitations_fmt, ids.length));
        } else {
            showMessage(getString(R.string.send_failed));
        }
    }
}
```

String[] ids are the array of Invitation id i have sent

Answer (score 1):

As the app, you can't get the list of person names and email, only the invitation ids. The email and names are private to the person who sent the invite, i.e. the person who owns the device and the contact data, and that private information is not shared with the app sending the invite.